# How to show stretch image in ImageButton in android

Tags: android

In my ui, i use image button for various actions.  In xml file as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/homebtn"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Home"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/homebutton"
    android:onClick="onHomeBtn"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/backbtn"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Back"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/backbutton"
    android:onClick="onBackBtn"
    />

<TextSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/infomsg"
    android:layout_width="550dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/exitbtn"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Exit"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:onClick="onExitBtn"
    android:src="@drawable/exitbutton"
    />
```

image shows output of ui.  Images in the button is not fully covered.  I not need border in the button.  How is possible ?

[image]

Comment: I Think make it as fill_parent...

Comment: use background instead of src attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
android:background="@drawable/backbutton"
```

instead of

```
android:src="@drawable/backbutton"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/homebtn"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Home"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
    android:onClick="onHomeBtn"
    />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/backbtn"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Back"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:background="@drawable/backbutton"
    android:onClick="onBackBtn"
    />

<TextSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/infomsg"
    android:layout_width="550dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/exitbtn"        
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Exit"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:onClick="onExitBtn"
    android:background="@drawable/exitbutton"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```